# Increment for combination of A-Z and 0-9 with unknown format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i got a table to save the invoice start number, which can let user define in any format, example:

ABC123

AZ2D20D7S99

but will force the user end with number

i got a table to save all the created invoice with **auto_increment**

so now, i need to display the invoice number with

**invoice start number** + the **auto_increment** id of invoices

example, i selected invoice id 11 from db, the invoice number should be

ABC134

AZ2D20D7S110

i thought can use preg_match and preg_replace but there is no standard format for the start number, so i guess its impossible unless there is standard format, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you force the user to **end with number**, so that is some sort of standard-format which you could use in a RegEx.

```
$regs = array();
$data="AZ2D20D7S110";
preg_match('/(.*?)(\d*\z)/', $data, $regs);
// use $regs[1] for matched number, increment it and append it $regs[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_match` to get the trailing number, and `preg_replace` to replace it with the new number:

```
$autoId = 11; /* this is the auto id from the database */
$id = "ABC134"; /* this is the user input */

/* find the trailing number and store it in $number */
preg_match("/[^\d]+(\d+)$/", $id, $matches);
$number = $matches[1];

/* increase the number by the database id */
$newNumber = $number + $autoId;

/* replace the old number with the new number */
echo preg_replace("/\d+$/", $newNumber, $id);
```

Explanation of the pattern /`[^\d]+(\d+)$/`:

- `[^\d]+` match one or more non decimal characters
- `(\d+)$` and then match one or more decimal characters that have to be at the end of the string (`$`)
- in `$matches[1]` the  matched string inside the first paranthesis is stored

Comment: this is ok for case ABC134, but AZ2D20D7S99 will converted to AZ2D20D7S121, which is wrong

Comment: no, the result is correct even for  AZ2D20D7S99, I just tested it.

Comment: weird, i tested it, it print AZ2D20D7S121

Answer (score 0):

With autoincrement it is possible to specify a prefix in another column and make the PK a combined column index. This has the added benefit that you need no code to maintain it or to query and display the data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: will take a look on it, but i guess is not useful in my case, because the prefix need to be able to edit in anytime